# Criar um método numa função envolvida

Tags: javascript

O [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) permite você criar envolver funções como pode ser visto [nessa resposta da SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326596/how-do-i-wrap-a-function-in-javascript) e [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258829/wrapping-a-function-in-javascript-jquery).

Com o auxílio dessas respostas eu consegui envolver uma função `spy`, como no código abaixo:

```js
function spy(func) {
  return function(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return func.apply(this, args);
  }
}
```

o que eu quero fazer agora é o seguinte, quando eu atribuir esse "envolvedor" (wrapper), eu quero que ele tenha um objeto acessível que me gere um relatório, por exemplo:

```js
var spied = spy(umaFuncao);
var report = spied.report();
```

E esse objeto tenha propriedades acessíveis, como, por exemplo, o número de vezes que o método envolvido foi chamado, por exemplo:

```js
console.log(report.totalCalls);//Será impresso no console o número de vezes que o método foi chamado
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso? Essa é uma questão que pode ser encontrada no [codewars](http://www.codewars.com/dojo/katas/5272be02d9a03e114b000877/train/javascript) e eu achei que seria interessante trazer para cá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode pendurar as propriedades que quer monitorar no próprio objeto/função que está retornando. Por exemplo:

```
function spy(func) {
    function spied(){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        spied.totalCalls++;
        return func.apply(this, args);
    }
    spied.totalCalls = 0;
    return spied;
}

var spied = spy(function(){});

spied();
spied();
spied();

console.log(spied.totalCalls);
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/8k4ph/1/</sup>

Se fizer mesmo questão de um método e do objeto *report*, aproveite-se da *closure* que está sendo criada:

```
function spy(func) {
    var report = { totalCalls: 0 };
    function spied(){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        report.totalCalls++;
        return func.apply(this, args);
    }
    spied.report = function() {
        return report;
    }
    return spied;
}

var spied = spy(function(){});
var report = spied.report();

spied();
spied();
spied();

console.log(report.totalCalls);
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/8k4ph/2/</sup>

Comment: o caminho parece ser mais ou menos por aí, mas se eu quisesse que o report, ao invés de um objeto fosse um método que retorna um objeto? Acho que eu me expressei mal na minha pergunta.

Comment: Eu entendi, mas no fundo nem o objeto seria necessário... totalCalls poderia ser pendurado em spied. Mas vou editar para fazer o que você pediu.